# Swift UILocalNotification: Is it possible to fire an event when Notification is displayed?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

So I know the didReceiveLocalNotification event is fired when a user selects an action on a Local Notification.

But, is an event fired prior to that when the notification is displayed as a banner or alert when the app is not active?  And can that be accessed to do some background code?

I am looking for an answer in Swift if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, local notifications do not and cannot awake the app when firing and the application is not active. The user must tap the notification, or perform a developer defined action on it before the app hears anything.

If you need your app to wake up, you need to use a remote notification with content available flag set.

Comment: Found this here(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1): "However, an app does not receive any callbacks until users interact with the alert and the app is allowed to access their location."

Comment: Yes. The user has to tap a notification for your app to hear the delegate callback.

Comment: Is it possible to access all past notifications (like when you swipe down from the top of your iPhone ) that have not been deleted from within the app

Comment: That's a good question. Not sure about that. Look at `scheduledLocalNotificantions` and see if they exist.